# git trouble deploying sinatra application with heroku

Tags: git, heroku, sinatra, datamapper

I'm just now getting into this stuff, so any help is welcome and appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I've written a Sinatra application and deployed to Heroku, but there is a bug somewhere. Running certain heroku commands like heroku open or heroku logs respond in the below error (here, shown for 'heroku logs'). I've installed Git Bash and a git gem, but using git in the command line doesn't work.

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.1.3/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:111:in ``
': No such file or directory -  git --version  (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.1.3/lib/heroku/helpers
.rb:111:in `has_git?'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.1.3/lib/heroku/helpers
.rb:116:in `git'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.1.3/lib/heroku/command
/base.rb:188:in `git_remotes'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.1.3/lib/heroku/command
/base.rb:166:in `extract_app_in_dir'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.1.3/lib/heroku/command
/base.rb:158:in `extract_app'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.1.3/lib/heroku/command
/base.rb:210:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.1.3/lib/heroku/command
/logs.rb:30:in `index'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.1.3/lib/heroku/command
.rb:117:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.1.3/bin/heroku:14:in `
'
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/heroku:19:in 'main>'
```

Comment: Have you tried running this command from the git bash instead of command prompt?

Comment: I just now tried, but it didn't work. I don't think Git knows anything about the Heroku gem

Comment: You ran Git Bash, and from its prompt you did `git --version`, and it didn't work?  What was the error message?

Comment: @olivier - Git Bash should be correctly installed. I've gotten version 1.7.4 installed from running git --version. My main problem was having heroku recognize git, as that seemed to be the root of the error i was receiving

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you installed msysgit, you probably chose the "Git Bash Only" option, which prevents you from running git from the command line (which is what the application is trying to do).  [Look here for a proper installation walkthrough.](http://lostechies.com/jasonmeridth/2009/06/01/git-for-windows-developers-git-series-part-1/)

You need to add the msysgit path to the `PATH` environment variable.  [Look here for instructions.](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Comment: Thanks for your help Olivier. Sorry, but could you give me more details about adding the msysgit path? Should I follow exactly the link you sent me or was that an example?

Comment: According to the installation guide, the default installation path is `C:\Program Files\Git`.  If that's where you installed msysgit, you would then have to add `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` to your `PATH` variable following the 2nd link's instructions.  (You basically have to tell Windows where to find Git.)

Comment: Thanks a ton. Got it working. Appreciate your time and timely responses

Comment: @dchang: You're welcome.  I don't know how close my answer was to the actual solution, but it is customary to accept the answer that solved your problem.  (If the solution was something else entirely, go ahead and answer your own question and accept your own answer.)